# Как заполнить данными spinner в alertDialog

Tags: java, android

Натыкаюсь на `java.lang.NullPointerException` когда пытаюсь назначить `adapter spinner`-у. Оно то и понятно, что пытаюсь заполнить `spinner` данными, когда `alertDialog` еще не открыт. Подскажите, когда и в каком месте нужно правильно назначать `adapter spinner`-у.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {


public AlertDialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    Spinner spinner;
    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, budgetItems);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    //тут ловлю Null
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    this.dialog = builder.create();
    this.dialog.setView(this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_item, null, true));
    }
}
```

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать задержку.

Comment: @pavlofff мне показалось, что тут и без кода суть проблемы ясна)

Comment: @pavlofff поправил вопрос... возможно Вы правы, а где именно, при создании диалога? Прослушиватель какой-то установить имеется в виду?

Comment: @pavlofff в MainActivity всё делаю... поправил вопрос еще раз.

Comment: я так понимаю, что сам спиннер находится в разметке `dialog_add_item.xml`, а не в `activity_main.xml`, где вы пытаетесь его найти?

Comment: @pavlofff всё верно, спинер находится в разметке кастомного диалога. Я тут немного с бубном попрыгал и вроде заработало
`LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);`
        `View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_item, null);`

и соответственно `this.dialog.setView(layout);`

Насколько ли верно я решил проблему?

Comment: @pavlofff Да, как Вы говорите - работает, но возник еще один вопрос. Я когда создаю `layout`
`View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_item, null);`
Вторым параметром отправляю `null`. Хотя по-хорошему, по документации, там должен быть элемент класса `ViewGroup`. Так вот в конкретно моём случае, что должно идти вторым параметром? Хотя оно работает и с `null`, но всё же интересно знать.

Comment: @pavlofff благодарю за помощь!

Comment: вообще о инфлейте разметки [максимально подробно](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/). Конкретно [по диалогу (почему там null)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24720976/7566397)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вам нужно искать ваш спиннер в разметке диалога. Сейчас вы ищите его в разметке активити, но его там нет и вы получаете null:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SER‌​VICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_add_item, null);
spinner = (Spinner) layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
```